# Different result mappings for the same query but with variable column - MyBatis 3

Tags: java, mybatis

I need to get different java Pojo result mapping from same query with different  column in sql "Where" condition.
Es.

```
@Select("Select field1,fiel2,...,fieldn From table where #{column}=1")
List<Pojo> getGenericDetails(@Param(column));
```

Mybatis "discriminator" doesn't make the job.
Can anyone know how to do that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you mean you need different fields to be chosen based on the column used in where condition

Comment: please add only relevant tags as these tags gets added up for those who answer your question

Answer (score 0):

If want to get different java Pojo result mapping from the same query with different column in SQL "Where" condition, I will try the following:

```
@Select("Select field1,fiel2,...,fieldn From table where #{column}=1")
List<Map<String,Object>> getGenericDetails(@Param(column));
```

as a result, the key in the map is the field1,fiel2,...,fieldn the value will be the result of field1,fiel2,...,fieldn.

Hope the above helps.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You inteed that in this way I get a list of key(field)String, value(list of field)Object, and after I use key to map result on different Pojo?

Answer (score 0):

The Mapping what you have written works But it works on same POJO .

If you need different POJOs based on the column in where clause then you Have to write  different queries for each of condition in where clause .

Which is as good as specifying column name in query .

So i suggest you to write different queryies and created Different POJOs and make the method name relevant to context where you will use those queryies

Comment: Hi Harsha tnx for reply, but the goal is just not to use multiple queries since what is changing is just a parameter representing the column. Otherwise I should make 5 different queries that do the same thing

Comment: in that case you have to use same POJO

Comment: Can I set return type of mapper in this way: List<T extends Pojo> and pass T different Object Type at runtime in myBatis?